# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\PermissionController::$permission

Tags: php, laravel

there is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class PermissionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

     public function _construct(Permission $permission)
     {
        $this->permission = $permission ; 
        $this-> middleware("auth") ;
     }

    public function index()
    {
        $permissions = $this->permission::all();
        return view("permission.index", ['permissions' => $permissions]);
    }

    public function getAllPermissions(){
        $permissions = $this->permission::all();

        return response()->json([
            'permissions' => $permissions
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `_construct` is missing one underscore. It should be `__construct`.

In your code, the class property `$permission` was supposed to be set by the constructor, but since you mistyped it, it never happened. That is why you get the undefined property error